# Помогите доработать Транслитератор

Tags: java, char, перевод

- - Проблема в преобразовании символа 'CH' в кириллицу Ч, нужно что бы
    он сначала проверял стоит ли после символа С символ  H, если стоит
    то преобразовать в русскую Ч.
- Нужно доработать метод lat2cyr.

  ```
  import java.util.HashMap;
  ```

  import java.util.Map;

  public class Transliterator {

  ```
  private static final Map<Character, String> charMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();

  static {
      charMap.put('А', "A");
      charMap.put('Б', "B");
      charMap.put('В', "V");
      charMap.put('Г', "G");
      charMap.put('Д', "D");
      charMap.put('Е', "E");
      charMap.put('Ё', "E");
      charMap.put('Ж', "J");
      charMap.put('З', "Z");
      charMap.put('И', "I");
      /*charMap.put('Й', "I");*/
      charMap.put('Й', "Y");
      charMap.put('К', "K");
      charMap.put('Л', "L");
      charMap.put('М', "M");
      charMap.put('Н', "N");
      charMap.put('О', "O");
      charMap.put('П', "P");
      charMap.put('Р', "R");
      charMap.put('С', "S");
      charMap.put('Т', "T");
      charMap.put('У', "U");
      charMap.put('Ф', "F");
      charMap.put('Х', "X");
      charMap.put('Ч', "CH");
      charMap.put('Ц', "C");
      charMap.put('Ш', "SH");
      charMap.put('Щ', "SH");
      charMap.put('Ъ', "'");
      charMap.put('Ы', "I");
      charMap.put('Ь', "'");
      charMap.put('Э', "E");
      charMap.put('Ю', "YU");
      charMap.put('Я', "YA");
      charMap.put('а', "a");
      charMap.put('б', "b");
      charMap.put('в', "v");
      charMap.put('г', "g");
      charMap.put('д', "d");
      charMap.put('е', "e");
      charMap.put('ё', "e");
      charMap.put('ж', "j");
      charMap.put('з', "z");
      charMap.put('и', "i");
      /*charMap.put('й', "y");*/
      charMap.put('й', "y");
      charMap.put('к', "k");
      charMap.put('л', "l");
      charMap.put('м', "m");
      charMap.put('н', "n");
      charMap.put('о', "o");
      charMap.put('п', "p");
      charMap.put('р', "r");
      charMap.put('с', "s");
      charMap.put('т', "t");
      charMap.put('у', "u");
      charMap.put('ф', "f");
      charMap.put('х', "x");
      charMap.put('ц', "c");
      charMap.put('ч', "ch");
      charMap.put('ш', "sh");
      charMap.put('щ', "sh");
      charMap.put('ъ', "'");
      charMap.put('ы', "i");
      charMap.put('ь', "'");
      charMap.put('э', "e");
      charMap.put('ю', "yu");
      charMap.put('я', "ya");
      charMap.put('%', "KH");
      charMap.put('^', "ZH");

  }
  private static final Map<Character, String> charMapEn = new HashMap<Character, String>();

  static {
      charMapEn.put('A', "А");
      charMapEn.put('B', "Б");        
      charMapEn.put('C', "Ц");
      charMapEn.put('D', "Д");
      charMapEn.put('E', "Е");
      charMapEn.put('F', "Ф");
      charMapEn.put('G', "Г");
      charMapEn.put('H', "Х");
      charMapEn.put('I', "И");
      charMapEn.put('J', "Ж");
      charMapEn.put('K', "К");
      charMapEn.put('L', "Л");
      charMapEn.put('M', "М");
      charMapEn.put('N', "Н");
      charMapEn.put('O', "О");
      charMapEn.put('P', "П");
      charMapEn.put('Q', "К");
      charMapEn.put('R', "Р");
      charMapEn.put('S', "С");
      charMapEn.put('T', "Т");
      charMapEn.put('U', "У");
      charMapEn.put('V', "В");
      //charMapEn.put('W', "В");
      charMapEn.put('X', "Х");
      charMapEn.put('Y', "Й");
      charMapEn.put('Z', "З");
      charMapEn.put('a', "а");
      charMapEn.put('b', "б");
      charMapEn.put('c', "ц");
      charMapEn.put('d', "д");
      charMapEn.put('e', "е");
      charMapEn.put('f', "ф");
      charMapEn.put('g', "г");
      //charMapEn.put('h', "х");
      charMapEn.put('i', "и");
      charMapEn.put('j', "ж");
      charMapEn.put('k', "к");
      charMapEn.put('l', "л");
      charMapEn.put('m', "м");
      charMapEn.put('n', "н");
      charMapEn.put('o', "о");
      charMapEn.put('p', "п");
      charMapEn.put('q', "к");
      charMapEn.put('r', "р");
      charMapEn.put('s', "с");
      charMapEn.put('t', "т");
      charMapEn.put('u', "у");
      charMapEn.put('v', "в");
      //charMapEn.put('w', "в");
      charMapEn.put('x', "х");
      charMapEn.put('y', "й");
      charMapEn.put('z', "з");
      charMapEn.put('\'', "Ь");
      charMapEn.put('%',"Ш" );
      charMapEn.put('5', "ш");
      charMapEn.put('^', "Ч");
      charMapEn.put('6', "ч");
      charMapEn.put('?', "Щ");
      charMapEn.put('7', "щ");
      charMapEn.put('*', "Й");
  }
  private static final Map<Character,String> vowels = new HashMap<Character,String>();

  static{
      vowels.put('A', "Я");
      vowels.put('E', "Е");
      vowels.put('U', "Ю");
      vowels.put('O', "Е");
      vowels.put('a', "я");
      vowels.put('e', "е");
      vowels.put('u', "ю");
      vowels.put('o', "Е");
  }

  private static String cyr2lat(String string) {
      StringBuilder transliteratedString = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
          Character ch = string.charAt(i);
          String charFromMap = charMap.get(ch);
          if (charFromMap == null) {
              transliteratedString.append(ch);
          } else {
              transliteratedString.append(charFromMap);
          }
      }
      return transliteratedString.toString();
  }


  private static Boolean isCyrillic(String text) {
      for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
          if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(text.charAt(i)).equals(
                  Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC)) {
              // contains Cyrillic
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }

  static boolean flag = false;
  public static String lat2cyr(String s){
      s = s.replace("null", "").trim();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){   // Идем по строке слева направо. В принципе, подходит для обработки потока
          char ch = s.charAt(i);
          String charFromMap = charMapEn.get(ch);
          if (charFromMap != null){
              sb.append(charFromMap);
              if (flag){
                  if (vowels.get(ch) != null){
                      if (sb.length()!=0)
                          sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
                      if (sb.length()!=0)
                          sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
                      sb.append(vowels.get(ch));
                      flag = false;
                  }
                  else
                      flag = false;
              }
              if (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y')
                  flag = true;
          }
          else{
              flag = false;
              sb.append(ch);
          }

      }
      return sb.toString();
  }

  public static String[] getTransliteratedNames(String name){

      String[] names = new String[7];
      if (name!=null && !name.isEmpty()){
          names[0] = name.replace("null", "").toUpperCase();
          if (isCyrillic(name)){
              names[1] = cyr2lat(names[0]).toUpperCase();
              names[2] = cyr2lat(names[0]).replace("X", "KH").replace("J", "ZH");
              names[3] = cyr2lat(names[0]).replace("X", "H");
          }
          else{
              names[1] = lat2cyr(replaceComplex(names[0].toUpperCase()));
              names[2] = lat2cyr(replaceComplex(names[0].toUpperCase())).replace("Е", "Э");
              names[3] = "";
          }
          }
      return names;
  }
  private static String replaceComplex(String src){
      src = src.replace("SH", "%");
      src = src.replace("SH'", "?");
      src = src.replace("CH", "^");
      src = src.replace("KH", "X");
      src = src.replace("ZH", "J");
      src = src.replace("Y'", "*");
      return src;
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: а что если после транслитерации сделать `string.replaceAll('цх', 'ч')` ?

Comment: При выполнении транслитерации пары соответствий всегда сортируются в направлении убывания длины искомого фрагмента. А вовсе даже не по алфавиту.

Comment: Исправил сам
В методе lat2cyr я вызвал метод replaceComplex();
s = replaceComplex(s);